# The og.likes cannot work for Pages or Photos

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have thought to use open graph to perform facebook like from my android app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes/

but I now see it won't work for fb pages and photos.

Then how can I perform like to `fb pages and photos` ?

```
The og.likes action can refer to any open graph object or URL, except for Facebook Pages or Photos.
```

Comment: You can't. Link people to the Facebook app and let people do it there

Comment: how to link? can I get ack that there like has been placed?

Comment: No you can not get an ack